# Estilos Css a tcpdf

Tags: php, html, css

estoy generando un archivo PDF con TCPDF y no encuentro la manera de darle estilo al texto usando CSS. Alguien me puede ayudar?

acá muestro mi código:

```
$pdf=new TCPDF();

$pdf->Addpage();

$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', 'B', 20);

$pdf->Write(0, '', '', 0, 'L', true, 0, false, false, 0);

// create some HTML content

$html="<h2>Recibo </h2>";

$html.="Buenos Aires, 12 de Diciembre de 2017. ";
$html.="Recibimos de el Sr. NOMBRE con DNI XXXXXXXX, estado civil XXXXXX, con domicilio en XXXXX, XXXXX
XXXXXXX, la suma de XXXXXx.- (XXXXXX 00/100 ), en concepto de Cuota, de acuerdo a las condiciones
que constan en el Boleto de Adhesión al Fideicomiso.";




<?php
$pdf->Ln();


// set core font
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);

// output the HTML content

$pdf->Ln();
// set UTF-8 Unicode font
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 10);

// output the HTML content
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, 0, true, true);

// reset pointer to the last page
$pdf->lastPage();

// ---------------------------------------------------------

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('Recibo.pdf', 'I');
?>
```

Comment: Y ya intentaste hacer los estilos de forma inline ? no se si sea lo mejor pero si funciona podrías ir explorando otras formas

Comment: Si, también lo intente agregando todo en una etiqueta <style> y solo agarra el cambio de color y tamaño en la fuente, del resto nada.

Comment: Has buscado algo en la documentación de TCPDF ? veré si encuentro algo

Comment: Mira lo que encontré para las fuentes...https://tcpdf.org/docs/fonts/

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió. Sabes si alguna otra librería que genere PDF que permita agregar mas estilos?

Comment: Pues que permita agregar estilos no se, pero otra librería que genera PDF es DOMPDF

Answer (score 0):

por lo que conozco yo TCPDF no soporta muchas etiquetas css. En cambio [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) si acepta más estilos css como color del texto, color de fondo, tipo le letra (TCPDF tambien). Ademas te permite jugar con las posiciones de cada elemento donde quieres colocarlo. Aquí te dejo un ejemplo que hice yo. 
[image: Ejemplo FPDF]

Otra opción que tienes es utilizar [Dompdf](http://Dompdf) personalmente no se mucho de el, pero se ve que se pueden hacer bastantes cosas con el.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Hola, sabes que diferencia en rendimiento haya entre usar las librerias que mencionas y HTML2PDF? también me hablaron de ella.

Gracias por tu ayuda, saludos.

Comment: No sabría decírtelo pero lo puedes comprobar tu mismo, una forma "cutre" de probarlo es mostrar cuando empezó y cuando acabo.